# Combining the numbers 2,3 and 4 with adjectives

Tags: іменники, прикметники, числівники, declension

In standard Ukrainian, what case marking will an adjective take if it proceeds the numerals 2,3 and 4? So far I've only ecountered contradicting information on this. One website told me these phases: Three white horses; four beautiful girls and two big windows, should be constructed as:

- три білі коні
- чотири красиві дівчата
- два великих вікна

The problem is, I talked with some people, and they told me it'd sound more natural if I said them as the following:

- три білих коня
- чотири красиві(их) дівчини
- два великих вікна

So which of these two versions is considered standard?

This is the follow-up on this question: [Case usage with the numbers 2,3 and 4](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/6682/)

Comment: For my native ear "три білі коні" and "чотири красиві дівчата" sounds wrong. What is the source for this usage examples?

Comment: @Physmatik Both of these: [https://studopedia.com.ua/1_224791_uzgodzhennya-prikmetnikiv-z-imennikami-pri-chislivnikah.html](https://studopedia.com.ua), [https://ukrainiangrammar.com/article/2012-06-15/the-numeral-few-more-rules.html](https://ukrainiangrammar.com)
At least the first one says you can use both genitive and nominative

Comment: I did not manage to find the phrases from your question on these sites.

Comment: https://ukrainiangrammar.com/article/2012-06-08/the-numeral-general-information.html - maybe it will help, look at "assembled: двоє (two), четверо (four), п'ятеро (five) etc."

Comment: http://pravila-uk-mova.com.ua/index/chislivnik/0-12