# Wiktionary, Ukrainian nouns, alternative emphasis

Tags: declension

I have been using Wiktionary to get conjugation & declension details, as well as a sense of pronunciation, and there is a nuance that is not explained.
For example, [дівчина](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) has two nominative plural options, ді́вчата & дівча́та where the difference is only the emphasis (as shown by the accent). And the links both go to the same place. There is a similar distinction for every possible declension, and no explanation that I can find for what this difference signifies. And when I search other resources it doesn't seem to get mentioned at all. Can someone explain to me what is going on here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do apparently identical words differ in spelling and declension?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2663/why-do-apparently-identical-words-differ-in-spelling-and-declension)

Comment: This a good question but a duplicate one. I agree with a previous commenter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### *Дівча́та* is correct, *ді́вчата* is dubious

I personally have no doubt that *дівчина* allows two emphases: *ді́вчина* and *дівчи́на* – still *ді́вчина* is more common. Some references:

- Both [R2U](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0&highlight=on) and [E2U](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) online dictionary collections mention both emphases. However *ді́вчина* is mentioned much more often.
- 20-volume explanatory “Dictionary of the Ukrainian language” (since 2010, work in progress) has separate entries for [ді́вчина](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=22578&page=770) and [дівчи́на](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=215753&page=770). However the latter is marked as folkloric/poetic.

However I've always heard only *дівча́та* (not *ді́вчата*). Some indirect proofs:

- Both [R2U](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0&highlight=on) and [E2U](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) online dictionary collections mention only *дівча́та*.
- [20-volume explanatory dictionary](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=22572&page=770) has entry only for *дівча́та*.

#### Source of information in Wiktionary

Let's look:

- Both articles in Wiktionary ([дівчина](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) and [дівчата](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0); archived versions: [дівчина](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?oldid=71447770), [дівчата](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?oldid=59635459)) refer to “Словозміна” dictionary in “Горох” online dictionary collection. (Also they refer to 11-volume explanatory “Dictionary of the Ukrainian language” (1970–1980), but the one doesn't support their claims, so it's irrelevant.)
- The correspondent entries in “Горох – Словозміна” ([дівчина](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0), [дівчата](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0)) refer to “Словники України online” online dictionary.
- The correspondent entries in [“Словники України online”](https://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) (sorry, I can't provide direct links to the entries, because that's not implemented in “Словники України online”) contain the same (partially self-contradictory) info as Wiktionary (the *дівчина* entry states that singular is *ді́вчи́на* and plural is *ді́вча́та*, while the *дівчата* entry states that plural is *дівча́та* and there is no singular). That's the primary source.

On the one hand, the maintainer of “Словники України online” is Ukrainian Lingua-Information Foundation, NAS of Ukraine; a certain level of trust is deserved. On the other hand, this online dictionary was somewhat [infamous for typos](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8_online#%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96_%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8); the maintainers make an effort to correct mistakes, but there's no guarantee they all are already corrected now.

#### Deeper immersion into morphology

Technically, *дівчата* isn't plural for *дівчина*. *Дівчина* belongs to the 1st declension (as *кішка*, *особа*, etc; and especially as *дитина*, *дружина*, *людина*, *тварина*; it's interesting that relatively high percent of *-ина* nouns have no plural / unusual plural), while *дівчата* belongs to the 4th declension and technically is plural for *дівча* (compare with other 4th-declension nouns: *ведмежа́* – *ведмежата*, *кошеня* — *кошенята*, etc; and especially to *-ча* ones: *дитинча* – *дитинчата*, *курча* — *курчата*).

| Singular | Plural |
| --- | --- |
| дівча (non-neutral) | **дівчата** |
| **дівчина** | дівчини (extremely rare) |
| **дівчинка** | дівчинки (rare) |

Practically, *дівчата* acts as plural for all three words: *дівча*, *дівчина* and *дівчинка*.

#### Conclusion

*Дівчата* is mentioned in “Словники України online” on three pages: *дівча*, *дівчата* and *дівчина*. Two of them provide emphasis *дівча́та* and only one page allow multiple emphases: *дівча́та* and *ді́вчата*. Most probably, the last one is just a typo, which got then spread to other dictionaries (“Горох” and Wiktionary); I'll try to inform “Словники України online” maintainers.